Symmetric groups acting on rational surfaces
Let $X$ be a complex projective rational surface. Is there an upper bound on $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $S_n\subset \text{Aut}(X)$? Here $S_n$ is the symmetric group on $n$ elements.

Your surface is rational in the title but not in the question. Why?

I forgot rational in the question.

Yes, $n\leq 5$. If $S_n\subset\operatorname{Aut}(X)$ with $S$ rational, $S_n$ embeds in the Cremona group $\operatorname{Bir}(\mathbb{P}^2)  $; this is possible only if $n\leq 5$.
This follows  from the classification of the finite subgroups of $\operatorname{Bir}(\mathbb{P}^2)  $, due to Dolgachev and Iskovskikh.

Which part exactly? It's a 100 pages paper.

The 100 page part, this whole paper is a proof of classification. // If you're satisfied with a less precise bound, Serre has shown that finite subgroups of 2-dim Cremona group have an abelian subgroup of bounded index (depending only on dimension); see J.-P. Serre. A Minkowski-style bound for the orders of the finite subgroups of the Cremona group of rank 2 over an arbitrary field. Mosc. Math. J., 9(1):193–208, 2009 (this reference is an English translation of Bourbaki seminar notes).
